# Getting input from the onscreen Keyboard using libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-input-method, on-screen-keyboard

I am trying to write a game and if they do something it will start up the onscreen keyboard.   Then, if they touch a few keys the game will change scenes to a bonus level.    I am currently using libgdx and it works great on the desktop version with a real keyboard.  I cannot get it to work on the android version.

In the render method:

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
    Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
    touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
    camera.unproject(touchPos);

    ...
} else if (touchPos.x > 0 && touchPos.x < 200 
           && touchPos.y > 0 && touchPos.y < 50) {
    Gdx.input.setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(true);
}
```

This works great.   The entire point of this is to get the keyboard to show up.   That it does do.  However, when I try to detect a key press with:

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)) {
    // Do What I need it to do.
}
```

I do not get a true value for this ever.  No matter what key or value.  How do I detect key presses from an on-screen Android keyboard in libGDX?

Comment: If you setup an `InputProcessor` to get input events (see http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputEvent) do the keyboard changes show up there?

Comment: It does.   I created a new class and stopped polling they key.   Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`Gdx.input.isKeyPressed` is polling the state of the keyboard, so it will only be true when the key is actually being held down.  That's probably not a state the on-screen keyboard can even report.

Switching to an [`InputProcessor`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html) 
makes it so each keyboard event is delivered as a distinct event.

See http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputEvent for more details.